# How to make a div fit the whole width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make the div with class ".shadow" fit the whole width. But I am unable to figure it out. The code I am using is given bellow.

```css
.main .container{
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}

.main .main-inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.shadow{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="main-inner">
            <div class="shadow">
                <img src="images/broadhurst.gif" alt="" class="logo-img">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="glenn-broadhurst.html">Glenn Broadhurst</a></li>//
                    <li><a href="#">Demand Calculator</a></li>//
                    <li><a href="clock.html">The Clock</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: It's likely that your `.main-inner`, and/or `.container` elements are not actually 100% as you are using table display type, set 100% width on these explicitly.

Comment: you can do ```.shadow{background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25); position:absolute; width:100%; left:0; top:0;}``` if class main-inner is position:relative it will fit to main-inner div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the whole width, you mean the whole page? if that's what you want then

`.shadow{background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25); width:100%;position:absolute}`

is what you're looking for
Edit: Oh, and don't forget to add width:100% to the other elements too

Answer (score 2):

For the div fit the entire page you need to clean the default margin given by brower, use this css.

Css:

```
.shadow{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
width: 100%; //this way its not fitting the entire page cause still have margin by default.
margin: 0px;
}
```

Hope I helped!

The actual accepted answer is incorrect btw.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do like this

```css
.main .container{
            margin: auto;
            width:100%;
            display: table;
        }
    
        .main .main-inner{
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            height: 100vh;
            
            text-align: center;
        }
    
        .shadow{
            background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25); 
        }
```

```html
<section class="main">
    <div class="container">
       <div class="main-inner">
           <div class="shadow">
               <img src="images/broadhurst.gif" alt="" class="logo-img">
               <ul>
                   <li><a href="glenn-broadhurst.html">Glenn Broadhurst</a></li>//
                   <li><a href="#">Demand Calculator</a></li>//
                   <li><a href="clock.html">The Clock</a></li>
               </ul>
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
   </section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main .container{
    margin: auto;
    display: table;
}

.main .main-inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.shadow{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25); 
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="main">
     <div class="container">
        <div class="main-inner">
            <div class="shadow">
                <img src="images/broadhurst.gif" alt="" class="logo-img">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="glenn-broadhurst.html">Glenn Broadhurst</a></li>//
                    <li><a href="#">Demand Calculator</a></li>//
                    <li><a href="clock.html">The Clock</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need "display:table" in your main container?

If not, then it's pretty simple. If you require "display:table", then please let me know, will check more then.

```
.main .container {
    display: block;
}

.main .main-inner {
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
}

.shadow{
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

by adding `width: 100%;` into your .shadow class it will be full size
aslo you can play around with height too to fit it.